# Not able to see the process and stacktraces of crash in Samsung Galaxy s2

Tags: debugging, android

I am not able to debug my application on Samsung Galaxy S2. I got a new phone last week. I am trying to keep my application on this (Samsung Galaxy S2) phone. But I observe that, in DDMS phone is listed but my process is not getting listed. So, i am not able to attach the debugger to my process.

And also when my application is crashing ("Force Close") error, i am not able to see the stack traces in Logcat even if i create a new Throwable object and call printStackTrace(). But in my application if keep logs (Log.i(), Log.e()...) i am getting those logs in the Logcat.

Do i need to do anything for getting the stacktraces and debugging the phone?
Please let me know if anyone have faced similar problem.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: make sure that USB Debugging is turned on in the Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for the inconvenience caused.
Actually in my app some one has kept this flag in the AndroidManifest.xml file
android:debuggable="false"
Due to which i was not able to debug. Now on changing it to true, i am able to debug. After a lot of lot of googling i came to know this.

Regards,
SSuman185